# R - Extract string based on its length from a column

Tags: r, regex

I would like to extract a string from a column if its length is between 6-10. These strings are separated by spaces.

Example:

```
Column A

" 3 89 -90/ 900407-2"
" 3 9 -90/ 900407-1"
"  89 -9011/ 800408"
```

Output should be:

```
   Output column

   900407-2
   900407-1
   800408
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There isn't enough logic here to give a foolproof rule for extracting the final string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
A <- c(" 3 89 -90/ 900407-2",
       " 3 9 -90/ 900407-1",
       "  89 -9011/ 800408")
gsub(".*/.*([0-9].*?)", "\\1", A)
#[1] "900407-2" "900407-1" "800408"
```

Comment: @sandipan- This solution worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
([\w+\-]){6,}
```

Matches every string with "-", {6,} mean 6 or more..

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/3BjrLW/1

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
x <- gsub(".* (.*)", "\\1", x)
```

If you want to restrict to strings with 6 to 10 characters, minus the hyphen, you can use:

```
lens <- nchar(gsub("-", "", x))  
x <- x[lens >= 6 & lens <= 10]
```